# Allow .svg logo uploading in theme settings

Tags: 8

How can I allow using .svg files for the logo field, in the theme settings?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Unnecessary restrictions on logo format: Can't upload replacement SVG logo](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2259567). You can find some patches that will enable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The logo field in the theme settings says it accepts `.svg` format but it actually does not.  As per the error message that comes up only `png jpeg jpg jpe gif` extensions are allowed at the moment. Its a bug that is being worked on [Unnecessary restrictions on logo format: Can't upload replacement SVG logo](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2259567). Try any of the patches mentioned in the issue and report there if your issue is resolved.

Alternatively, for your theme (or custom theme) you can just put the logo.svg in the theme folder and modify the page.html.twig template file to use the .svg extension.